# MongoDB Query: How to get the all values of a nested field where parent node is dynamic?

Tags: mongodb

Here is the sample of one of the documents in our collection in MongoDB. I need to get all the values of the **NUMBER** field from all the documents in this collection with a MongoDB Query. What could be that Query?

```
{
"_id" : "5w1669ba-3f8a-4695-a585-9fa510d13e59",
"display_title" : "SWE Test Series!",
"production_year" : "2020",
"type" : "series",
"created_timestamp" : 1597940264,
"seasons" : {
    "8c399fbc-dc65-4c2e-b86c-5c6289835b45" : {
        "number" : "1",
        "uuid" : "8c399fbc-dc65-4c2e-b86c-5c6289835b45",
        "created_timestamp" : 1597940441
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a language through which you want to do this. Is this done via Python, JavaScript or some other language?

Comment: I wanted only a raw query that I can run in Robo 3T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that.

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N-R--EA6mRI)

`objectToArray` makes it easy.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "a": {
        "$objectToArray": "$seasons"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$a"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "a.v.number": 1
    }
  }
])
```